# Can OpenCL inline functions return OpenCL types?

Tags: function, types, inline, opencl

I know OpenCL supports inline functions, but can those functions accept and return OpenCL types?

Specifically, I am interested in something with this signature:
float4 func(float4 x, float4 y)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for most GPUs, all functions are inlined anyway, even if you don't specify it.

Comment: As far as I know, ATI's and NVidia's CL compilers *always* inline for performance reasons. The hardware can support function calls, but it's slow.

Answer (score 4):

Only kernel functions has a specific return type which is void. Any other function can return any valid OpenCL type.